# Kendo Grid , Set simple filter

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are finaly migrating from Telerik MVC Extensions to Kendo and I am having a problem trying to apply a static pre filter to a kendo grid.

I am trying to filter out the rows that contain the word "Archived" in the status column.

How do I do this using Kendo?

Below is the Telerik MVC extensions method that I am trying to convert

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {                    
        columns.Bound(m => m.Id);   
        columns.Bound(m => m.Status);               
        ...
    })
    .DataBinding(......)              
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Filters(filters =>
    {
        filters.Add(m => m.Status).IsNotEqualTo("Archived");
    }))              
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this filter before you retrieve the datasource ie. you don't want the server to present the results back for `Archived` or pull the data back then filter. Also are you doing filtering serverside or client side?

Comment: I want to pull back the data and then filter on the clientside

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it from the clientside after getting back the initial dataSource [demo showing client side filtering](http://dojo.telerik.com/IloBo)

With this example which is the the javaScript version we leverage the DataBound event and when the grid is rebound to the `dataSource` we run this function:

```
  function onDataBound(e){
            var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid'); 

            if(initialFilter)
            {
                grid.dataSource.filter( { field: "ShipName", 
                                          operator: "contains", 
                                          value: "Han" });
              initialFilter = false;
            }

          }
```

`initialFilter` is a global variable which is a `bool` that will allow us to control this function and run it once. Otherwise this will keep going in a loop.

then applying the filter to the dataSource we have three parts to it.

`{{fieldName},{operator},{value}}`

So in this example I am looking at the ShipName, filtering where the value `Han` is contained in the shipName.

to attach this via the mvc version just add it to the events option
i.e.

```
.Events(event => event.DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

another way of doing this is to apply the filter during initialization of the grid and that way the data is filtered without having to go through the issues presented by the first version. [filter at initialization](http://dojo.telerik.com/obejo)

With this version I am merely changing the dataSource and applying the same filter as part of the dataSource setup like so:

```
 dataSource: {
     type: "odata",
     transport: {
         read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
     },
     schema: {
         model: {
             fields: {
                 OrderID: {
                     type: "number"
                 },
                 Freight: {
                     type: "number"
                 },
                 ShipName: {
                     type: "string"
                 },
                 OrderDate: {
                     type: "date"
                 },
                 ShipCity: {
                     type: "string"
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     pageSize: 20,
     serverPaging: true,
     serverFiltering: true,
     filter: {
         field: "ShipName",
         operator: "contains",
         value: "Han"
     }
 },
```

So in your datasource configuration you would add something like this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("",""))
.Model(model => {model.Id("ShipId");})
.Filter(filter => 
                {
                  filter.Add(f => f.ShipName).Contains("Han"); 
                })
```

Hopefully this gives you a good starting point but if you need any more info let me know and I will expand the answer for you.